# How to test whether an optional module is present at runtime

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

The Java Platform Module System (JPMS) allows a module to declare an optional dependency using `requires static` in the `module-info.java` file:

```
module my.module {
    requires static some.optional.module;
}
```

However, how should you check in your code whether the module is present at runtime?

The [Project Jigsaw: Optional Modules](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/topics/optional.html) page proposed:

```
public boolean isModulePresent(String mn);
```

But, it appears that was dropped because there is no such method in the latest Java releases. Neither am I able to find the `@RequireOptionalModule` annotation mentioned there in the current Java version.

[This example on blog@CodeFX](https://blog.codefx.org/java/module-system-optional-dependencies/) suggests a quite verbose method chain on `StackWalker` (which is explained [here](https://medium.com/codefx-weekly/javaland-50-off-j9ms-stack-walking-3d377452db0c)).
Edit: That example tries to find out if a module is available to the caller class, which is not necessary in my case.

Is there an easier way to perform this check, or can a simple `Class.forName` check suffice if the presence of a certain class indicates that a module is present?

Comment: Do you have a special use case in mind? If you know that an optional dependency will be added during the start of an application (with `--add-modules`), using `ModuleLayer.booth().findModule(String)` should do the job. `Class.forName(String)` will check if a *class* is present — theoretically it could be in another module than expected or in the unnamed module.

Comment: The solution on CodeFX is mine. Unfortunately, it needs to be so complex. If module _A_ checks whether module _X_ exists, `ModuleLayer::findModule` must be called from _A_'s layer. An `isModulePresent` method can be in a different layer than _A_, though, and so it first needs to determine _A_. That's what my code uses the StackWalking API for.

Comment: @Nicolai so your solution tries to provide a general utility method which can be used by any module. But if the "is module present" check happens within the code which then also uses classes of that module, the check does not have to find out the caller, right?

Comment: Right. If the method does not find the caller's module's layer first, it determines whether code in the layer that it itself belongs to reads the specified module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if some module is available at runtime, you can simply call [ModuleLayer.findModule()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#findModule(java.lang.String)):

```
Optional<Module> module = ModuleLayer.boot().findModule("java.desktop");
System.out.println(module.isPresent());
```

`Class.forName()` should work too if you know the name of some specific class from the module. However, `forName()` throws `ClassNotFoundException` if a class is not found. This means you will have to surround it with `try-catch` to make it work. This is not very convenient.

Comment: Thanks, it appears using the boot layer should work for most cases, but it might not work when someone uses custom module layers. Getting the module of the current class and then its layer to find the module might solve this though (but I am not sure).

Comment: @Marcono1234 Yes, you are right. If you use multiple layers, you should substitute `ModuleLayer.boot()` with your current module layer.

Comment: What's "your current module layer", though? Chances are, an `isModulePresent` method is not in the same module as the caller, so searching from the module that contains the method may be insufficient. To achieve correct results, the caller module's layer should launch the search. Why is why [my solution](https://blog.codefx.org/java/module-system-optional-dependencies/#Internal-Dependency) appears so complex.

Comment: The current module layer is given by getClass().getModule().getLayer(). Keep in mind it may return null if you are not inside a ModuleLayer.